# JaCoCo code coverage on interface implementations using @Autowired

Tags: java, testing, reflection, jacoco

I've created an interface for my tests which contains default methods. At the moment, it looks something like this:

```
public interface CRUDTest<
        Controller extends ControllerCRUD<Model, DTO, Creation, Update, Service>,
        Service extends ServiceCRUD<Model, Creation, Update, ? extends GenericRepository<Model>>,
        Creation extends CreationDTO<Model>,
        Update extends UpdateDTO<Model>,
        DTO extends ModelDTO,
        Model extends GenericModel> {

  Controller getController();
  Service getService();
  ImageService getImageService();

  Creation generateCreationDTO();

  default void doStuff() {
    service().createFromDTO(generateCreationDTO());
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then, each test implements this interface in the following way:

```
public class Implementation implements CRUDTest<ExampleController, ExampleService, ExampleCreationDTO, ExampleUpdateDTO, ExampleDTO, ExampleModel> {

  @Autowired @Getter private SongService service;

  @Autowired @Getter private SongController controller;

  @Autowired @Getter private ImageService imageService;


  @Test
  public void doStuff() {
    CRUDTest.super.doStuff();
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell, the "createFromDTO" method in my service should now be reported as covered by JaCoCo, and it is obviously called when running the tests. However, JaCoCo reports the method as uncovered, so I'm wondering what I might be missing.

Comment: JaCoCo records execution of instrumented classes independently from the way they were executed (directly, via reflection, or somehow else). And provided example is definitely not [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and hence not enough to understand you difficulties.

Comment: @Godin I've switched to a different approach to avoid reflection, but the end result is the same. I've added a more complete example which I'm hoping will prove sufficient.

Comment: No it is not sufficient. Can you provide really full example, where one doesn't need to guess how method `getService` works, how you compile, how execute tests, and how you generate coverage report? For example as a project at GitHub?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue! The project I'm working on follows a multimodule structure, and some of the integration tests included methods from a different project. These methods were thus not covered by JaCoCo, but some googling leads me to believe there's several ways to fix this.